# Show bootstrap tooltip with restrictions

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

For every tag that have the `title` I am showing a tooltip with:

```
$('[title]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

But I would like to do not show if there is a specific class, like `selectbox`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options I believe. You can use the CSS :not() selector like this:

```
$('[title]:not(.selectbox)').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

or use the jquery not() selector like this:

```
$('[title]').not('.selectbox').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

I believe the second one is accepted as being the more readable of the 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[title]').not('.selectbox').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```